# Retrieving form field attribute in django

Tags: python, django, forms, view, attributes

I have an input text field in my form which has an important new attribute added via JavaScript. The attribute name is `fieldid`.

Is there a way to retrieve this attribute and its value from the view after the form is summited?

Comment: Can't you just change the javascript to add the value to a hidden field ?

Comment: No. Pass these values in hidden fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributes on form elements are not passed on to the server when forms are submitted; only input element values are.

The way to add extra information to be sent back to a server on a form submit is by adding additional `<input />` elements to your form, specifically `<input type="hidden" />` elements.

E.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="foobar" value="spam and eggs" />
```

adds a new field `foobar` to your form data with the value `spam and eggs`.