# how to get id of the input text field in Django Views?

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-forms

Currently in my form I have this:

```
<input type="text" name="textAnswer" maxlength="50" id="ed57a954-7afd-47ac-b6d4-979198455aa5" class="textinput textInput form-control">
```

I want the id of this input in views when form is submitted.
I know how to get the value typed by user in textInput in views but I don't know how to extract id of that input as well.

Currently I'm extracting Value with this code:

```
 userTypedValue = request.POST.get('textAnswer')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can an id of input field can be read by PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500164/how-can-an-id-of-input-field-can-be-read-by-php) I know the target is for PHP but it is same for Django (or any webserver), only the name and value of the input fields are posted.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667171/retrieving-form-field-attribute-in-django this might help

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can add new field to store id.

```
#forms.py

from django import forms

class SomeForms(forms.Form):
    id = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={               
                "class": "form-control"
            }
        ))
    value = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={               
                "class": "form-control"
            }
        ))
```

then, in view to use form data

```
# views.py
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def someform_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SomeForms(request.POST)
        ....
```

Remember to pass from to view

```
front.html
<input type="hidden" value="ed57a954-7afd-47ac-b6d4-979198455aa5">
```